# Raising Errors in SQL Server ( THROW Command) with IF condition - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am trying to update my script from the `RAISERROR` command to the `THROW` command. I am in an `IF` statement condition and if the condition is true, the throw the error. For the `RAISEERROR` command I do not have an issue, however when I change to the `THROW` command, there is no possible.

`RAISERROR` command:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Auction.uspAddProductToAuction
    (@ProductID INT,
     @ExpireDate DATETIME = NULL,
     @InitialBidPrice MONEY = NULL) 
AS
    DECLARE @IND_ADD_PRODUCT TINYINT
    SET @IND_ADD_PRODUCT = 1

    IF ([Auction].[ufnGetStock](@ProductID) = 0) --> true
    BEGIN
        SET @IND_ADD_PRODUCT = 0
        RAISERROR ('The product is not in auction campaign discount or a product was not inserted', 1, 0)
    END
```

THROW command:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Auction.uspAddProductToAuction
    (@ProductID INT,
     @ExpireDate DATETIME = NULL,
     @InitialBidPrice MONEY = NULL) 
AS
    DECLARE @IND_ADD_PRODUCT TINYINT
    SET @IND_ADD_PRODUCT = 1

    IF ([Auction].[ufnGetStock](@ProductID) = 0) --> true
    BEGIN
        SET @IND_ADD_PRODUCT = 0
        THROW 50001, 'The product is not in auction campaign discount or a product was not inserted', 0 
    END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspAddProductToAuction, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 180]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
The statement before the THROW statement must be followed by the semicolon (;) statement terminator.

```
SET @IND_ADD_PRODUCT = 0;--<--!!
THROW 50001, 'The product is not in auction campaign discount or a product was not inserted',0;
END
```